# How to convert a VirtualBox virtual machine to QEMUwto image?

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, qemu

How do I convert a VirtualBox virtual machine to a QEMUwto image?

Comment: You may need to take an intermediate step and find a common format you can convert to as a stepping stone. There are various conversion utilities out there, I've had mixed success with them. The Open XenServers conversion tool may be a really handy first step.

Comment: @The White Phoenix thanks for the post! I was able to convert using VBoxManage convertdd path_to_vdi_file path_to_new_raw_file

Comment: duplicate to the previous (can't delete my comment)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Qemu-img should do the job, command line example here:

```
qemu-img convert Windows.vmdk -O qcow2 Windows.qcow
```

If you have any issues, this article I spotted on-line should address them:
http://blog.bodhizazen.net/linux/convert-vmware-vmdk-to-kvm-qcow2-or-virtualbox-vdi/

Comment: Thanks for the post! I was able to convert using VBoxManage convertdd path_to_vdi_file path_to_new_raw_file

Comment: Cool, if you like the posts, upvote us! :)

Comment: But when I am starting to load it. it says "no bootable device" any ideas?

Comment: Maybe the conversion didn't work properly - is there any way you can fire up a LiveCD of some description in your VM and try browsing the hard drive from that?